# Saving RichTextBox FlowDocument to image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, printing, richtextbox

i'am making a programm where i want my  RichTextBox 
content (text+images) to be saved as an image (jpg/png). I tried to use [this solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5978a7f1-7e7e-48f7-a0b4-aad6a6310c02) 
but i get only black filled image from

```
SaveUIAsGraphicFile()
```

I also tried to create FormattedText from my rtb control, printing it works fine, but its not possible to insert images in there. Maybe it is possible to print FlowDocument somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like the following method to create a bitmap from a FlowDocument:

```
public BitmapSource FlowDocumentToBitmap(FlowDocument document, Size size)
{
    document = CloneDocument(document);

    var paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)document).DocumentPaginator;
    paginator.PageSize = size;

    var visual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (var drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        // draw white background
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, new Rect(size));
    }
    visual.Children.Add(paginator.GetPage(0).Visual);

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height,
                                        96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bitmap.Render(visual);
    return bitmap;
}

public FlowDocument CloneDocument(FlowDocument document)
{
    var copy = new FlowDocument();
    var sourceRange = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
    var targetRange = new TextRange(copy.ContentStart, copy.ContentEnd);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        sourceRange.Save(stream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
        targetRange.Load(stream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
    }

    return copy;
}
```

and then use it like shown below to save a RichTextBox's Document to an image file.

```
var doc = richTextBox.Document;
var bm = FlowDocumentToBitmap(doc, new Size(richTextBox.ActualWidth, richTextBox.ActualHeight));
var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bm));

using (var stream = new FileStream("doc.jpg", FileMode.Create))
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it works, but how do i get the rtb client size in wpf, to fit all the content in image?

Comment: You might use the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the RichTextBox. I've edited my answer to show that.

Comment: I tried using them, but for some reason they always returns same values 300/100. And doesnt change with text input. I have  `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` set. Could this be the problem?

Comment: You may also try `ExtentWidth` and `ExtentHeight`. Note that I added a `CloneDocument` method to my code sample, as I realized that accessing the Paginator of the original document interferes with the RichTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example of default column pagination]

You can spend HOURS chasing around trying to figure out why the width is wrong when in reality its trying to paginate in columns. Set the document's columnwidth to the full width of your output bitmap.

```
    public Bitmap FlowDocumentToBitmap(FlowDocument document, Size size)
    {
        document = CloneDocument(document);
        document.ColumnWidth = size.Width;// <-  Add this line
```