# Images in a RichTextBox (FlowDocument)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, richtextbox, flowdocument

I can "import" an image (picking a file) and wrap it in Border in an inlineUIContainer.
- But then, when I save the document, the image disappears (very short file).

OR I can paste it in from clipboard (no Border wrapper).
- Then it does get saved with the document - but I have no control over the display...

What's the correct way to import an Image (from a file) and keep the actual bitmap
in the FlowDocument, so it can be saved with the rest of the RichText ?

EDIT:
My problem seems to be, that the image is represented (in XAML) with a URI
- not the actual bitmap - so HOW to import/embed it correctly ?
This is my import code:

```
string fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Absolute));

Image image = new Image();
image.Source = bitmap;
image.Width = bitmap.Width;
image.Height = bitmap.Height;

Border border = new Border();
border.Background = Brushes.Blue;
border.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(10);
border.Margin = new Thickness(10);
border.Padding = new Thickness(10);

border.Child = image;

InlineUIContainer box = new InlineUIContainer(border, rt.CaretPosition);
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895745/saving-richtextbox-flowdocument-to-image

Comment: Thanks Techidiot, but that's not it at all. I just want to save the document with the images "inside" - not export the document AS an image.

Comment: Why must every little thing be such nightmare of hacks and workarounds in WPF ?!? I'm now trying to cheat by using the clipboard internally, but that is also insanely hard AND doesn't allow transparency (png and gif) SO close to giving up on WPF altogether...

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating the Image in a [Viewbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a Border like so:

```
string fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Absolute));

BlockUIContainer blockUI = new BlockUIContainer();
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = bitmap;
Viewbox vb = new Viewbox();
vb.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.DownOnly;
vb.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
vb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
vb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
vb.Child = img;
blockUI.Child = vb;

rt.Document.Blocks.Add(blockUI);
```