# WPF - Convert Rich text box contents to a bitmap image

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, richtextbox

Is there any way I can convert the contents of a rich text box to a bitmap in WPF?

I tried the solution mentioned in the following post: [Saving RichTextBox FlowDocument to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895745/saving-richtextbox-flowdocument-to-image)

But my dilemma is I am unable to figure out how to calculate the required size of the bitmap before hand that would cover the entire flow document.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`FlowDocument`s don't have a rigid size, that's the point:

[Flow Document Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview):

> Flow documents are designed to optimize viewing and readability. Rather than being set to one predefined layout, flow documents dynamically adjust and reflow their content based on run-time variables such as window size, device resolution, and optional user preferences.

You need to set either a height or a width restraint, or both. If you set only one, width for example, the `FlowDocument` will update to stretch vertically until all the content has been displayed. After you set the constraint(s), you can check the actual size of the document and that will give you the required size of your image.